# Is it possible to access an attribute of a child class from the parent class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a parent class where I am defining store-relation function, and a child class which defines its table on the store. In the parent class, I'm defining a `save()` function which connects to the instance's table, but the table is defined on the child. I figured I could just set the constructor of the parent to accept the child's `tableName`, but my linter is complaining that `super` must be called before I reference `this` (even though I want to pass an attribute on `this` up to super).

Here's the parent:

```
export class StoredObject {
    constructor(private tableName: string) {}

    public save() {
        store.collection(this.tableName) //...
    }
}
```

And the child:

```
export class Inventory extends StoredObject {
    tableName = "inventory";

    constructor(
        public myVar //...
    ) {
        super(this.tableName)
    }
}
```

I know one solution is to make a getter function that simply returns the value of `this.tableName`, but that seems hackish. I also know that I could simply put the actual string in `super` (e.g., in `Inventory`, have the constructor be `{ super("inventory") }`, but that seems inelegant. I get the suspicion there is a way of conventionally achieving what I'm trying to do, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I think you have an error in your code. You never define tableName as a variable so I believe it is in global scope, further more this.tableName will not reference the private variable tableName which is stored in the scope (if you put var in front) but not part of the object that is accessible. Try this.tableName = "inventory".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Ryan Cavanaugh's response here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1617#issuecomment-69215655)

Specifically,

> The order of initialization is:
>
> 1. The base class initialized properties are initialized
> 2. The base class constructor runs
> 3. The derived class initialized properties are initialized
> 4. The derived class constructor runs

You've made your super class responsible for initializing the tableName property and it must be able to do that before your subclass can be created. You'll either have to pass in "inventory" or alter this relationship.